# How to change model property before validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have conditional server validation and I want to set property on which condition is specified before validation.

I have following acion method in webapi controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ModelRequired]
[ActionName("Register")]
public object Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

How to change property in my model before validation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you're decorating the Model with attributes and you need to modify a property before it gets validated then you could either create a new validation attribute that will take that into account or create a custom action filter.

Comment: What do you mean by "conditional server validation"? Can you go into more detail about how that works please? It might help make the question clearer.

Comment: I have RequiredIfAttribute (http://mvcdiary.com/2013/02/28/conditional-required-validation-or-field-mandatory-depends-on-another-field-mvc-4/) and when !RegisterModel.IsCustomer then address field is required. I want to set this property to true when controller instance is RegistrationController.